How to reference an item in a table using a custom index in excel?
I have a 2d grid in excel here calculating for a board game hobby, finding an "engine rating"

I also have a separate table as follows, linking the "engine rating" to an "engine weight".

What I want to do is add a part to my formula in the 2d grid that checks if the associated engine weight would be more than 90% of the mech weight (the left column of the grid) and if so display 0 instead of the calculated number. So lets say on my grid we have the entry for 50 mech tonnage and and 8 MP, the associated cell is 400. On my table one of the rows in the "Engine rating" column is 400, and I want to reference the same row in the "Engine Tonnage" column. In this case the associate engine tonnage would be 52.5. So I want to add to my grid formula a way to check for that case and instead of displaying 400 display 0. Is this possible to do?
I have tried searching for similar problems and looking up table referencing online as well as search through all the related table syntax in excel but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for yet.

Check this formula in B34 and copy to right and down.
=IF(0.9*$A34<VLOOKUP($A34*B$33,$M$34:$N$63,2,FALSE),$A34*B$33,0)
The #N/A results is for the no matching in the Engine rating column.


would there be a way to change the N/A into showing a 0?

Look into IFNA

Or IFERROR(statement,0)
